# simple_form: required vs. optional fields via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, simple-form

I have a form using simple_form, and trying to update some optional fields in it to required with AJAX.

In the Rails js.haml template, I am adding the class 'required' to the field label and input, e.g.:

```
$("label[for=some_label]").addClass('required')
$("input[id=some_input_id_here]").addClass('required')
```

but it does not work.

Has anyone done a similar thing with AJAX and simple form?

Another option is to re-render the form from the js.haml template, and to set :required => true for the necessary fields, however I think this is an overkill.

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: re-render? if you put required-true into the template the first time you render, it shouldn't need it to be done later by AJAX...

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, initially the fields are not required. Then based on some AJAX event, e.g. a user selecting something, the same fields can be required or not, thus has to happen via AJAX.

Comment: Ah right... well - that should probably have been a part of your original question ;) You might want to edit your question and add this important information there so people that are trying to help you actually understand all the relevant info. otherwise we'll keep giving you answers that would be helpful to the original specification you gave, rather than what you actually need.